# Are there other functions that can result in "StartIndex cannot be less than zero"?

Tags: c#, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

We have a customer who is reported receiving an error message along the lines of "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex". This is a standard error message usually thrown in the `Substring` and `Remove` functions of the `String` class. Unfortunately, I am unable to get ahold of the data that this is failing on for them, so I'm forced to debug this by looking at the source code.

I have looked for all incidences of `Substring` and `Remove` and verified that their StartIndex parameter could not be less than 0. I searched for all uses of "startIndex" and verified that, in the two cases where they were being used as the first parameter of a string function, it could not mathematically be less than 0 (in both cases, it was given the return value of an `IndexOf` function, but then a string `Length` and the value of 2 were added to it, so 1 is the smallest value it could have).

This suggests to me that either this is an issue which was fixed in prior codebases, they have a nonstandard codebase, or I'm looking in the wrong place. Are there any other functions in C# that raise this sort of error text? Or is there any way in which it could be reporting the wrong input parameter? Am I just misunderstanding this error message?

Comment: Can you get a call stack from the customer?

Comment: Can you not get a hold of a stack-trace?

Comment: Adding to Golden Dragon's comment - the windows event log may have recorded the stack trace for you

Comment: We most probably can't help you very much in this case. Unless you log the information somewhere, the information is lost.

Comment: I believe this can also happen with a blank string. Is it possible that you're getting a blank string as input? Or, have you protected those Substr and Remove calls with if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)) { ... }?

Comment: @Markus: `IsNullOrEmpty()`. It was my first thought, too, but the `+2` he's adding should guard against that.

Comment: `startIndex` is typically an `int`. Any chance the value is actually really large and just overflowed the `int`?

Comment: @ClickRick Yeah, you're right. In my tests, it would throw an out of range exception anyway and not the mentioned starting index exception.

Comment: I.e., the problem is significantly more difficult than expected. We're trying to get the customer to give us more data, but it's slow going. Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: I'm afraid that I have no update. With the customer's files, we can't trigger the error, and the event logging of stack traces was apparently removed due to security concerns. Pretty much a waiting game until they come up with something more for us to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's 91 methods from System.dll and mscorlib.dll:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var names =
            GetMethodsWithParameter(typeof(object), "startIndex")
            .Concat(GetMethodsWithParameter(typeof(Uri), "startIndex"))
        .Distinct();
        foreach(var name in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetMethodsWithParameter(Type assemblyOrigin, string name)
    {
        foreach(var type in assemblyOrigin.Assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            foreach(var method in type.GetMethods(
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static))
            {
                if(method.GetParameters().Any(x => x.Name == name))
                {
                    yield return type.FullName + "." + method.Name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more than just `Substring` and `Remove` with `startIndex` parameter:

- [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3z4t9d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`String.IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56y4ddbk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [`String.LastIndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbkt4sh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Most of above with several overloads which contain `startIndex` parameter.

You should definitely get a call stack, otherwise it will be really hard to find place where problem occurs.